# How do I delete files older than N days?

Tags: mac, macos

The content in my Downloads folder is getting bigger and bigger. There are many older documents that I don't need any more. Is there a way to bulk erase files from a given number of days ago?

Comment: Automatically would be dangerous. Simply sorting by date & selecting multiples would at least give you the opportunity to check first what was about to be trashed.

Comment: This looks like a spam seed ...

Answer (score 1):

Sure - a safe way is to have a backup like Time Machine - you can then delete files knowing you can restore them with ease.

I like to sort a file listing by date - select the first file to be deleted, scroll to the end of the list leaving that one file selected. Then use shift to select the last file - shift then selects the entire range.

Then put all the files in trash. Once you're sure your backup was was good or you selected the correct files - empty the trash.